# Sorting Tableview Rows By Multiple Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, pfquery

I am currently trying to sort my tableview by the words on the labels in each row. Each row will have 3 things: a color, a animal type, and the name for the animal. I have a specific order in mind on how I want to organize the table, but depending on how the items are loaded, the order of the rows can be anything (the problem).

I want to sort these tables by color by this array: `colorArray = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "purple"]`. This mean that all the red animals will be first while all the green ones will be in the middle etc. ***First problem* is that I do not know how to sort an array by another string array**. ***Second problem* is that I need the other two arrays (animal and animal name) to change their order in accordance with the color array so the right animal and their names' will be with the correct color.**

*Example:* if the color array are loaded in like `blue, green, orange, red` and the animal array is loaded in like `dog, cow, cat, monkey`, I will then need then need these two array to be sorted into `red, blue, green orange` and `monkey, dog, cow, cat`. This is so all the animals are with the right color. **How do I fix these two problems?** I have copied my current code at the bottom:

```
    func loadAnimals() {
            let animalQuery = PFQuery(className: "Animals")
            animalQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId! ?? String()) //getting which user
            animalQuery.limit = 10
            animalQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.colorArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.animalNameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)                
                    self.animalTypeArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

                    for object in objects! {
                        self.colorArray.append(object.value(forKey: "colorType") as! String) // add data to arrays
                        self.animalNameArray.append(object.value(forKey: "animalName") as! String) // add data to arrays                    
                        self.animalTypeArray.append(object.value(forKey: "animalType") as! String) // add data to arrays
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                } else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? String())
                }
            }
        }

    //places colors in rows
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! AnimalCell //connects to color cell

            //Adds the animal information in the cells
            cell.colorType.text = colorArray[indexPath.row] 
            cell.animalName.text = animalNameArray[indexPath.row] 
            cell.animalType.text = animalTypeArray[indexPath.row] 

            return cell
        }
```

Comment: Use **one** custom struct or class rather than multiple arrays. It makes life much easier and solves your problem collaterally. For the colors use an index to get a custom order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use multiple arrays as data source. They are error-prone and annoying to maintain. Use a custom struct, this is a object oriented language.

- Create this struct, the color string will be mapped to an index and vice versa

  ```
  struct Animal {

      static let colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "purple"]

      let name : String
      let type : String
      let colorIndex : Int

      init(name : String, type : String, color : String) {
          self.name = name
          self.type = type
          self.colorIndex = Animal.colors.index(of: color)!
      }

      var color : String  {
          return Animal.colors[colorIndex]
      }

  }
  ```
- And this data source array

  ```
  var animals = [Animal]()
  ```
- Replace `loadAnimals()` with

  ```
  func loadAnimals() {
      let animalQuery = PFQuery(className: "Animals")
      animalQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId! ?? String()) //getting which user
      animalQuery.limit = 10
      animalQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
          if error == nil {
              animals.removeAll()

              for object in objects! {
                  animals.append(Animal(name: object["animalName") as! String, type: object["animalType") as! String, color: object["colorType") as! String)
              }
              self.tableView.reloadData()

          } else {
              print(error?.localizedDescription ?? String())
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- And `cellForRow` with

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! AnimalCell //connects to color cell

      //Adds the animal information in the cells
      let animal = animals[indexPath.row]
      cell.colorType.text = animal.color
      cell.animalName.text = animal.name
      cell.animalType.text = animal.type

      return cell
  }
  ```
- Now sort `animals` by `colorIndex` and you get the order you want

  ```
  animals.sort{ $0.colorIndex < $1.colorIndex }
  ```

Comment: I implemented this in my code and the `animals` load! But I am not sure how to sort them by the `colorIndex` as this is my first time using structs. **How do I implement their sorting properly?**

Comment: Ok I implemented it in my and now the rows are being organized by color! But now there's another problem: **the animal names are being mixed up. They are not staying with their correct colors** How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand. The properties `name`, `type` and `color / colorIndex` always stick together

Comment: Hmm maybe that was just a hiccup in the code because I've been testing it since I posted the last comment and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks for all your help!